Which parameter must be set when creating an event in icalender and the event lasts the whole day (alldaylong)?
I would like to set dates without time (from and to) and the checkbox for alldaylong should be set when opening the dialog of the event
..cant find any descriptions or manuals referring to this problem
..there are some posts and proposals , but none of them work
for example
event.add('dtstart', datetime(int(datum[6:10]),int(datum[3:5]), int(datum[:2]), tzinfo=pytz.utc))
event.add('dtend', datetime(int(datum[6:10]),int(datum[3:5]), int(datum[:2]), tzinfo=pytz.utc) + timedelta(days=1))

